# how to listen to Enter button when using JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane

I use:

```
    char[] password = null;
    JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField(30);
    java.lang.Object [] messageInput = { prompt, jpf };
    java.lang.Object [] options = { jpf , "OK", "Cancel"};
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, messageInput, title,
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, options, "");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    result);

    if (result == 1) {
        password = jpf.getPassword();
    }
    else if(result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {


    }
    return password;
```

to get password, but this can not listen to the Enter button.
I know if I set the options parameter to null, can make the dialog listen to "enter" button, but if I do that, the dialog don't focus to the textbox when show up.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know if I set the options parameter to null, can make the dialog listen to "enter" button, but if I do that, the dialog don't focus to the textbox when show up.

[Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) should help you out.